# security settings between Amazon EC2 instance and heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm creating a redis instance in ec2 that I want my heroku app to be able to access.  Are there specific inbound source ip ranges or security settings I can set in Amazon ec2 security groups to only allow traffic from my heroku instances?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATE: Heroku no longer publishes it's security groups so this is no longer possible.

Comment: thanks, setting it the source to 098166147350/default did the trick.

Comment: If I read the docs right, this solution only sets up ec2 inbound traffic for ALL heroku apps, not just your specific ec2. Which seems to be a security problem for most.

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the caveat (noted in sidebar of external-services link) that this approach will not work if you are in a VPC?

Comment: the only solution afaik to deal with the vpc issue, is to avoid it!  You cannot attach external security groups (one's that aren't under your aws account) to public facing elb's in your vpc.

Comment: For those confused about the misterious number 098166147350: yes, it's a "magic number", tied to Heroku's account in AWS. Just use it

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to note that Heroku no longer recommends using the AWS account ID to grant access to other services running on AWS. Details here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/353

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos can make any outbound tcp connection to anywhere.

Comment: was interesting in limiting the inbound security of my ec2 instance, not the outbound connections from heroku...

Comment: Ahh. I misread the question.  But glad that it got answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo

Then you will be able to use AWS security groups.

Comment: would this still use the low latency ec2 to ec2 connection?  Or would it get routed outside then back in?

Comment: is there a free way to achieve this?