# AWS Allowing inbound access from Heroku for forward proxy to external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-ec2

I have a rails 3.2 app running on Heroku which needs to proxy requests to an external API from a static IP address. Since Heroku doesn't offer elastic IPs, and Proximo is too expensive and limiting for the number of requests I need to make, I set up a simple forward proxy on an AWS EC2 micro instance in US-East using mod proxy.

I can proxy requests from my app's local environment just fine. However, requests from heroku time out. My thinking is that, since I can proxy from my local environment, the point of failure must be the connection between Heroku and my Proxy box.  I've tried the answer given here: [Security settings between ec2 and heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636835/security-settings-between-amazon-ec2-instance-and-heroku) but it didn't work.  I've even tried allowing all inbound access on port 80 (even though that's terrible for the internet).

So, my question is, what are the security settings that I should enable for my ec2 instance in order to allow Heroku to proxy through it?

Comment: Interesting problem. Did it work with Proximo development, since only $5, curious if there was at least a round trip success.

Comment: I didn't try it with Proximo, although I suppose that would be my next step. But, like I said, it's working locally, so it must be something obvious that I'm missing. Or maybe not :-P

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos are all running on machines within Amazon EC2 us-east-1 data center.  They do not have any restrictions/firewalls on outgoing connections.

As long as you have the proper Security Group settings to allow the connections from your dynos to your own EC2 instance, you should be good.

It sounds like you haven't correctly opened up access from within us-east-1 to your instance.  Double check your security group.

Information on how to edit the correct security group:

1. Check what security group you are using for your instance. See value
   of Security Groups column in row of your instance. It's important -
   I changed rules for default group, but my instance was under
   quickstart-1 group when I had similar issue.
2. Go to Security Groups tab, go to Inbound tab, select HTTP in Create
   a new rule combo-box, leave 0.0.0.0/0 in source field and click Add
   Rule, then Apply rule changes.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how do I allow inbound access from the us-east region?

Comment: Edited to add detail on finding the right SG and how to allow all for 80.